# How to disable floating action button in android

Tags: android, floating-action-button

In simple buttons we do

`android:clickable:"false"`

```
button.setEnabled="false"
```

Is there any way to simply disable floating action button? I repeat i am not asking about hiding i am asking about disabling floating action button.

Answer (score 11):

It can be done just like a button.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab)         
fab.setEnabled(false);
fab.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your FabButton you can do this:

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(getActivity());
    fab.setEnabled(false);
```

That disables the OnClick() of the FAB

Answer (score 1):

You can use the api

```
fab.setEnabled(boolean state);
```

[Sample](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/11/disable-floatingactionbutton.html)